# Legend issue with fill / geom_tile in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using geom_tile, and have found what seems to be a bug in how the legend is displayed. Running this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(0)

DT = data.frame(x = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3), y = rep(letters[1:3], by = 3), value = rnorm(9))

g = ggplot(DT, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value)) + geom_tile()
print(g)
```

produces a chart with a blank colour bar for the legend (which I can't currently post because I don't have enough reputation for images).

Running R.Version() gives:

```
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "0.2"

$year
[1] "2013"

$month
[1] "09"

$day
[1] "25"

$`svn rev`
[1] "63987"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)"

$nickname
[1] "Frisbee Sailing"
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with R 3.0.2 and ggplot2 0.9.3.1.

Comment: @user3423201, Have you tried it without the use of `print`?

Comment: I also cannot reproduce your error. I've got ggplot2_0.9.3.1, R version 3.0.3 & OS X 10.9.2

Comment: Works for me; exact same R.Version(). Have you tried restarting your R session?

Comment: I was running this code via remote desktop, and I'm pretty sure it was an issue with that specific implementation of RStudio. I also wasn't able to reproduce the example in other implementations of R. Thanks to those who checked.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I have the same problem running R on RemoteDesktop. On my desktop, everything is working fine..